# XML Parsing Error: no element found

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

Going through new questions with new tags in Moderator Tools, I clicked on a tag "machine.config", and got the following error:

```
XML Parsing Error: no element found
Location: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/machine.config
Line Number 1, Column 1:
```

The URL is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/machine.config.

BTW, the same happens for "web.config". I suppose it's the dot.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2850/the-great-tagging-reorg/2930#2930

Comment: Brad, this wasn't my question. I was retagging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Brad makes the point about which tags you should use instead... but that doesn't address the fact that it really is a bug. You shouldn't be able to "break" SO just by feeding it a tag of a particular format.

It's not a particularly *major* bug, I'll grant you... but definitely one to fix.

I don't believe it's the fact that there's a dot though - I believe it's ASP.NET trying to prevent people from getting the *actual* machine.config/web.config etc.

Other interesting finds:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foo.aspx: page not found
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foo.asax: broken (no source)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foo.asbx: suitable empty list of questions

When it's broken, in Chrome I don't get an XML parsing error - I just get an empty page, with no data at all even when viewing source.

Comment: Yeah, the XML parsing error is Firefox's response to an empty page served as XHTML (application/xml).

Comment: Interesting. In IE I just get a 404 error.

Comment: man. thank you, guys. ive spent weeks on a similar problem on my system. thank *you*!